# Python is missing after installing via Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've installed VS2019 (Enterprise) and marked Python 3 in the individual components  tab:
[image]

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#install-locations) it should reside in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python` but actually there is no `Python` dir under `Microsoft` dir.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the python path under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared`
I've also opened an issue against the documentation page so it will be updated there as well